Is there a way to immediately shut down without "sd X: Stopping Disk" on Linux
The sysrq+o is known to immediately shut down a Linux machine, and known for being similar to physically removing power source.
It actually does so on small setups where there are not many ATA devices.
But, recently I was playing with a multi-ATA setup with 19 spinning disks. And I figured out that sysrq+o does not immediately shut down. Instead, it attempts to "stop" all SCSI disks first. (It doesn't happen if I use sysrq+b for Reboot).
On such big setups, stopping disks can take some time, up to 5-6 seconds, during that time I see this in console:
[819386.342761] sysrq: Power Off
...

[819389.901812] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdh] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[819389.902581] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdh] Stopping disk
[819390.723593] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdk] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[819390.723871] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdk] Stopping disk
...

And so on.
It turns out that sysrq doesn't immediately power a system off.
Is there a way to do it? Why do I need to "stop disk" in order to power off? Is there any way to make it similar to unplugging the power cable? If not, can it be accomplished from kernel code?
